# How to determine the worst case complexity for my algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, heap

I was writing `siftup` algorithm for heaps and I am stuck at then end of the question. The last part of the question says The algorithm should have logarithmic worst case time complexity, i.e. `O(log(n)`. I have written the algorithm below, where `i` is the index of the element in the heap and `v` is the heap array. The index of the root is the lowest while its maximum for the lowest child of the heap. I am considering the arrays go from 1 to n

**Algorithm**

```
Siftup (v, i) {
While(v[i] > v[i/2] and i != 0) {
    Temp = v[i] // Temp is of the same type as v[i]
    v[i] = v[i/2]
    v[i/2] = temp
    i = i / 2
    }
}
```

Since the process involves four assignment statements in the `while loop` each having constant worst case timing, the algorithm should have a logarithmic worst case time complexity. Can any one show an approach to determine its `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in heap?

P.S. Please also let me know the errors in my algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like your algorithm has logarithmic complexity.

I'd agree with your observation that each iteration appears to have constant complexity.

The step after that is figuring out how many iterations will execute for a given value of N. While I'm not going to provide a direct answer to that, the key here is the `i = i / 2`. This may be easier to look at in reverse: for some given N, how many times do you have to double `i` (starting from 1) before it'll reach that N? More specifically, what is the relationship between the size of N and the number of times you need to double `i` before it's at least as large as N?

Comment: will the condition `i != 0` not work for the purpose, since that is the point where the value of the element will stop sifting up?

Comment: @buzzinga: I'd have to think about that for a moment -- I think it probably works, but I'm not sure (when I've written a heapsort in C++, I've cheated and used 1-based indexing).